# Call subroutine where parameter contains ampersand in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I call a subroutine with a parameter being a variable containing an ampersand (&)?

There is no error, but the call never seems to execute.

**example.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

rem Doesn't work
set val=with^&ampersand
call :Output !val!

rem Works fine
set val=without_ampersand
call :Output !val!
goto End

:Output
set "line=%1"
echo Called: !line!
goto :eof

End:
```

**Output:**

> Called: without_ampersand

**Edit:**

The usage of *delayedExpansion* is not required. It was just used in this example. A way to do it without using delayedExpansion is preferred.

The question is focusing on "How do I call" rather than "How do I initially set the variable". The variable may come from user input or a `for /f` loop (as is my case).

Comment: & is a reserved character, which you need to escape https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741546/how-to-input-special-character-in-cmd

Comment: @spikey_richie In my example, I have escaped it using `^`. But it won't pass the value to the subroutine.

Comment: You are using delayed expansion, so I suspect you might need _a lot more_ escaping...

Comment: If you go back to basics and just do set val=test^&test at the command prompt, then just run set without a value does the list return val=test&test?

Comment: Just as grawity said.... try `set val=with^^^&ampersand` so a lot more escaping.

Comment: @gawity I edited the question as delayed expansion is not required for the question. I just used it in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batch escape rules are quite nasty, but the behavior is totally predictable if you know the rules.

The info you need to understand the problem is available at [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053) in phases 1, 2, 5, and 6 of the accepted answer. But good luck absorbing that info any time soon :-)

There are two fundamental design issues that lead to your problem:
 - Phase 6 doubles all carets, which then restarts phase 2 (actually phases 1, 1.5 and 2).
 - But phase 2 requires `&` to be escaped as `^&`. Note it must be a single `^`, not doubled!

The only way to get your approach to work is to introduce the `^` after the phase 6 caret doubling has occurred.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ESC=^"

rem Calling with delayed expansion value
set "val=with%%ESC%%&ampersand"
call :Output !val!

rem Calling with a string literal
call :Output with%%ESC%%^&ampersand

exit /b

:Output
set "line=%1"
echo Called: !line!
goto :eof
```

ESC is defined to hold `^`.
The first round of phase 1 expands `%%ESC%%` to `%ESC%`
the second round of phase 1 (initiated by phase 6) expands `%ESC%` to `^`

This is all totally impractical, especially if you don't know what the content is going to be.

The only sensible strategy to reliably pass any value into a CALLed routine is to pass by reference. Pass the name of a variable that contains the string value, and expand that value within your subroutine using delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "val=with&ampersand"
call :Output val
exit /b

:Output
set "line=!%~1!"
echo Called: !line!
exit /b
```

Comment: Wow. Okay. That link was informative, and kind of scary, reading :) . But the option of passing by reference seems to be the real solution in this case. Thanks for the well written answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you add an additional `^` and quotation marks it will work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

rem Doesn't work
set "val=with^^&ampersand"
call :Output !val!

rem Works fine
set "val=without_ampersand"
call :Output !val!
goto End

:Output
set "line=%1"
echo Called: !line!
goto :eof
```

---

`SET LOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` requires 2 escape characters:

`ECHO 123 ^^& 456^^!`  will output `123 & 456!`.

You should also use `SET` always with quotation marks!

Comment: Since it is the calling (rather than the setting) that is in question, do you mean I must do a replace (`set val=!val:^&=^^^^^&!`) prior to the call? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nope - That cannot work because of CALL caret doubling

Comment: @ANisus Oversaw that, sorry. But do you really need the `&` combined with `call` there? If so, you could edit the variable and replace the `&` with something else which you then replace again with a `&` later on. Or you simply use the word `and` (if that's the purpose of the `&` here).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for me, as the & was still being read as a command separator, but I came up with this (the last for loop is for demonstration and should be modified or removed as needed):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "file=pathwith&orwithoutampersandand!exclamation"
call :execute
exit /b

:execute
for %%A in ("%file:!=" "%") do (
    if [!file_conc!]==[] (
        set "file_conc=%%A"
    ) else (
        set "file_conc=!file_conc!^^^!%%A"
    )
)
set "file=!file_conc:"=!"
set "file_conc="
for %%A in ("!file:&=" "!") do (
    if [!file_conc!]==[] (
        set "file_conc=%%A"
    ) else (
        set "file_conc=!file_conc!^^^&%%A"
    )
)
set "file=!file_conc:"=!"
set "file_conc="
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('cmd /c ""!file!" "%error_log%" %ldt%" 1^>nul') do stuff
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Poison chars like `<>|&` are safe within quotes. You have to use quotes each time, you have to handle (define or use) them (or escape them). That starts with the `set` command (variable definition), continues with the parameter to `call` (variable usage), and continues (but by far doesn't end) with the `echo` command (variable usage).

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "val=with&ampersand"
call :Output "%val%"
exit /b

:Output
set "line=%~1"
set line
echo problem without quotes: %line%
echo ok with quotes: "%line%"
echo ok with escaping: %line:&=^&%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%line%") do echo ok with for: %%a
```

Output:

```
line=with&ampersand
problem without quotes: with
Der Befehl "ampersand" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
ok with quotes: "with&ampersand"
ok with escaping: with&ampersand
ok with for: with&ampersand
```